# How to Check in Mysql either the date is valid or not?

Tags: mysql

i want to ask about Mysql (date)

i have a set of data that has a date using data type varchar
so i want to update the real table ,but in the real table the data type is date
when i want to update , it show error like this

> Error Code: 1292
>   Incorrect date value: '1975-11-31' for column 'dob' at row 1

and i realize that the date in not valid...
so how supposedly i get the valid date only?

please help me..

this is my query

```
UPDATE ori_table a      
INNER JOIN set_of_data dd ON dd.old_id = a.id   
SET a.dob = dd.dob_new   

WHERE a.id IN (SELECT old_id FROM set_of_data    
WHERE status_color = 0    
AND dob_new IS NOT NULL   
AND age != '#VALUE!'   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,6,2) <= 12   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,6,2) >= 01   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,1,4) <= 2018   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,9,2) <= 31   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,9,2) >= 01)   

AND a.dob IS NULL
```

Comment: What's the example output?

Comment: the ouput is the date that only valid on calender example 1996-06-01 is valid 1977 -11-31 is not valid

original data
no | date 
1   | 1996-01-06 
2   | 1977-11-31

expected result

no | date 
1   | 1996-01-06

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking all the parts of the date individually as you are (and what you have won't work as it will still allow November 31 or February 30 as a date), just check to see if MySQL thinks it's a valid date by passing it through [`DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) and checking for a non-NULL result. So replace

```
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,6,2) <= 12   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,6,2) >= 01   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,1,4) <= 2018   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,9,2) <= 31   
AND SUBSTRING(dob_new ,9,2) >= 01
```

with

```
AND DATE(dob_new) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hi @jazz can you give me some more information about what is not working?

Comment: ouhh when i remove the condition and add the STR_TO_DATE function like u as me to do i get 0 row data .

Comment: @jazz it seems `STR_TO_DATE` doesn't work as expected in all cases. Try my edited version

Answer (score 0):

Is the `dob_new` type date of mysql? If it is, why don't you use `dob_new between '2018-01-01' and '2018-12-31'`

Comment: Ok, you can try execute only sql of `SELECT old_id FROM set_of_data    
WHERE status_color = 0    
AND dob_new IS NOT NULL   
AND age != '#VALUE!' AND STR_TO_DATE(dob_new, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NOT NULL` and see the result.

Comment: i got the data but it still have a not valid date in it like 1975-11-31

Comment: `SELECT old_id FROM set_of_data WHERE status_color = 0 AND dob_new IS NOT NULL AND age != '#VALUE!' AND STR_TO_DATE(dob_new, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'`

Comment: still get the not valid date..im sory